# Please help me identify my childhood manga about a boy fighting in a tournament

Tags: ranma

It is a martial art themed manga about a boy fighting in a tournament. One of the character fought using only legs.

If I recall correctly, the main character turned into girl if he got splash with water, though I'm not sure how he turned back into a boy.

There is a vivid image of a panda back in my head but really not sure if it is related.

I believe this manga came out during Dragon Ball era.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it's [**Ranma 1/2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranma_%C2%BD)
[image]

> On a training journey in the Bayankala Mountain Range in the Qinghai Province of China, Ranma Saotome and his father Genma fall into the cursed springs at Jusenkyo (呪泉郷). When someone falls into a cursed spring, they take the physical form of whatever drowned there hundreds or thousands of years ago whenever they come into contact with cold water. The curse will revert when exposed to hot water until their next cold water exposure. Genma falls into the spring of a drowned panda while Ranma falls into the spring of a drowned girl.

Comment: Now I know the mystery behind turning into a panda and a girl.